# Update query not work when data is too long

Tags: php, mysql

When data in text area is update using update sql query,

its updating only when the size of text area data is small,

but when we update like paragraph through text area its not working

in simple words, when the size of data entered in text area is big its not updated in sql database

(if its a small word its updating if its big paragraph its not updating)

$sql="UPDATE table SET column1='$value',column2='$value'  WHERE  condition";

This is the condition syntax.

i tried data type to long text too its not changing

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the structure of the database. You will want the variable type to be a bigger string type.

take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp specifically the types of strings and their limits.

happy coding :)